# GBQ - Execute INSERT query ONLY if SELECT query returns results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question has been asked before in many forms. But none of the solutions proposed worked for my case.

I am using GBQ.

I have this table:

```
        Hour            Orders
2022-01-12T00:00:00       12
2022-01-12T01:00:00       8
2022-01-12T02:00:00       9
```

I want to create a query to **insert data** into this table automatically **per hour**, under these conditions:

- If the "most recent hour" that I want to insert already exists, I do not want to insert it twice.

I tried the following SQL query :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `Table` WHERE Hour = var_most_recent_hour) 
    UPDATE `Table` SET Orders = var_most_recent_orders WHERE Hour = var_most_recent_hour
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `Table` (Hour, Orders) VALUES (var_most_recent_hour, var_most_recent_orders)
```

This syntax is returning an error in GBQ, although the SQL syntax is usually accepted.

Is there a way to do this?

**My priority is to insert without duplicates.**
I don't care about the UPDATE part in my query.

Ideally I want something like (I know this syntax does not exist):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `Table` WHERE Hour = var_most_recent_hour) 
    INSERT INTO `Table` (Hour, Orders) VALUES (var_most_recent_hour, var_most_recent_orders)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you use the MERGE statement, instead? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Sample code below

```sql
declare  most_rcnt_hour time;

INSERT INTO dataset.targettable(...

SELECT *
FROM dataset.targettable T
JOIN (SELECT most_rcnt_hour AS most_rcnt_hour) as S
ON T.rcnt_hour <> S.most_rcnt_hour
```

Note that IF in BQ works differently. [IF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if)

Comment: Seen as my priority is to insert without duplicates (added this to my ticket now), MERGE doesnt help me. I tried to do this query without "WHEN MATCHED" part, left only the "WHEN NOT MATCHED" part, and it updated everything in my table (I was using a test table)

Comment: Updated code...